Get with PowerShell if the local account was changed to a Microsoft account
I have a Windows 10 computer where I created a local user account used by multiple people.
Occasionally, users sign in with their Microsoft accounts, and these accounts remain signed in. I can see the Microsoft account on top in the Settings app, but it is still listed as a local account in the Control Panel.
How can I accurately detect if the current user is signed in with a Microsoft account using PowerShell?
I tried this already:
(Get-LocalUser User).PrincipalSource 

Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "SID=$sid" | Select -Expand AccountType

Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount | Where-Object { $_.LocalAccount -eq $true }

All these commands return that the account is a local account, but in fact in the setting app on top I see a Microsoft account signed in.
Update:
After deeper digging, I found that this happen when they sign in in Microsoft office and choosing 'Use this account everywhere on your device' then the acount is not listed as a Microsoft acount under (Get-LocalUser $user).PrincipalSource  but shows a Microsoft acount in top of the settings app.

"...a local user account used by multiple people." Is it security principle #1 or #2 that says no account can be shared?

@lit that's an opinion, which I happen to generally agree with, but that's not relevant to OP's question, who is asking about a situation where there apparently is a need for a shared local account
